# write a code that takes two string arguments and return integer count of number of times an argument can be found in another argument

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I have to write a code substrn, which takes string arguments sup and sub, and returns the integer count of the (possibly overlapping) number of times sub can be found in sup.

I wrote this code

```
def substrn(sup,sub):
   if sub in sup:
      x = 0
      for i in sup:
         if sub in sup[sup.index(i):(int(len(sub))+int(sup.index(i)))]:
            x = x +1 
      return x 
   else:
      return 0

print(substrn("wooloomooloo", "oo"))
print(substrn("wablabmablab", "ab"))
```

Can anyone help me understand what went wrong with my code and how I can change it? My first print statement produced 8 but my second print statement produced 4, they should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Here try this instead:

```
def substrn(sup,sub):
       # if sub in sup: # this is redundant since you are already checking 
      x = 0
      for i in range(len(sup)):
         if sub == sup[i:int(len(sub))+i]: 
         # try not to use a in b as this indicates partial search
         # so to make your logic more explicit you use a == b 
            sup[i:int(len(sub))+i]
            x = x +1 
      return x 


print(substrn("wooloomooloo", "oo")) # prints 4
print(substrn("wablabmablab", "ab")) # prints 4
```

The main problem in your initial code is this portion `for i in sup:` and `sup.index(i)`.

`for i in sup:` iterates through each letter in `sup` and `sup.index(i)` will only find the **first** occurrence of the index of `i` in `sup`. It does not care about where `i` comes from, but only what `i` is.

If you actually printed out `sup.index(i)`, you'll find that `sup.index(i)` will always be `1` for each loop, and hence when u execute `substrn("wooloomooloo", "oo")` it will always capture the first `oo`. Since you have 8 `o`s, your `substrn("wooloomooloo", "oo")` will return 8

I hope this helps :)